# XAML minimize/maximize/close buttons through SystemCommands

Tags: wpf, xaml

There's a WPF class called `SystemCommands`. I've seen examples of these commands being used on buttons to perform common window tasks like maximize, minimize and close.

One of the examples I found looked like this (simplified):

```
<Window x:Name="MainWindow">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Close"
                Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MainWindow}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When I start the application the button is disabled and I can't click it. Changing the `IsEnabled` property has no effect.

I managed to get the button to be enabled once, but I'm not able to reproduce it now. In any case, when it was enabled, nothing happened when I clicked it.

What must I do to get this button enabled and to actually close the window (or minimize/maximize)? I would really prefer it to be a XAML only solution if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are only predefined RoutedCommand(s) without any implementation. You must provide the implementation by yourself.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcommands

> The commands in the SystemCommands class represent a set of common
>   commands that manage a Window. The properties in this class represent
>   RoutedCommand objects and do not provide the implementation logic for
>   the command. You can provide the logic for a command by binding the
>   command with a CommandBinding. Alternatively, the SystemCommands class provides static methods that implement the logic for the specified Window. You can pass a static method to a type that implements ICommand and that accepts a delegate. For more information, see the example in the InputBinding class.

Comment: I see. This makes me curious, though. What is the point of these commands if you have to provide your own implementation anyways? What advantage does the SystemCommands have that a regular button click event handler does not?

Comment: `RoutedCommand` is a bit of a holdover from before WPF went full MVVM.  In the MVVM pattern you would be using your own `ICommand` implementation.  The benefit there is that the command code lives in the viewmodel, not the view.  `RoutedCommand` *does* have one benefit though.  You can raise one from anything that supports it, but handle it anyplace in the visual tree through `CommandBinding`.

Comment: This would allow you to have any number of user controls on a window that have their own "Save" button.  You could then catch that command at the window level, since `RoutedCommand` bubbles up the visual tree, like events do.  That lets you have the save logic in one place, but "raisable" from anywhere,

Comment: Thanks for the good explanations. Unfortunately it looks like I'm on the wrong path :(

Comment: @GTHvidsten, I suppose, the point is to provide members for commonly used commands. A kind of "do not repeat yourself" :)